Exporting an image collection to drive from GEE using Python, code runs but no images found in Google Drive
I'm using the following python code to export a range of image bands to my google drive, it is using an excel file to get the site name and coordinates. Currently, there is only one site name with polygon coordinates present in the excel file, as I just wanted to check the code works first. When I run the code, everything works, except I see nothing in my Google Drive. Any recommendations would be much appreciated.
import ee
ee.Initialize()
ee.Authenticate()
import pandas as pd
import datetime

# Load the Excel file
excel_file = r'C:\Users\Beach_Location_Coordinates.xlsx'
df = pd.read_excel(excel_file)

# Function to create a polygon geometry from coordinates
def create_geometry(row):
    coords = [
        [row['Long1'], row['Lat1']],
        [row['Long2'], row['Lat2']],
        [row['Long3'], row['Lat3']],
        [row['Long4'], row['Lat4']],
        [row['Long1'], row['Lat1']]  # Close the polygon
    ]
    return ee.Geometry.Polygon([coords])

# Define the export function with site name in the filename
def export_image(image, band_name, site_name, region, scale, folder):
    task = ee.batch.Export.image.toDrive(
        image=image,
        description=f'{site_name}_{band_name}',
        folder=folder,
        region=region,
        scale=scale,
        crs='EPSG:4326'
    )
    task.start()
    status = task.status()
    print(f"Exporting {band_name} band for {site_name}... Task status: {status}")

def get_image_date(image):
    try:
        # Retrieve the capture date and time
        date = ee.Date(image.get('system:time_start'))
        #date = ee.Date(image.get('system:time_start')).format('yyyyMMdd_HHmmss').getInfo()
        return date
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error retrieving date for image: {e}")
        return 'unknown_date'

# Iterate over each site in the DataFrame
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    site_name = row['Site_Name']
    print(site_name)

    # Create the polygon geometry from coordinates
    polygon = create_geometry(row)

    # Define a Sentinel-2 image collection and filter by location
    collection = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2_HARMONIZED') \
        .filterBounds(polygon) \
        .filterDate('2021-05-01', '2024-06-30') \
        .sort('system:time_start')

    # Select the first image in the collection
    image = collection.first()


    # Get the capture date and time with error handling
    #date = ee.Date(image.get('system:time_start')).format('yyyyMMdd_HHmm').getInfo()
    date = get_image_date(image)
    #print(date)

    # Select individual bands for export
    red_band = image.select(['B4'])  # Red
    green_band = image.select(['B3'])  # Green
    blue_band = image.select(['B2'])  # Blue
    nir_band = image.select(['B8'])  # Near Infrared

    # Export each band with site name and date in the filename
    region_coords = polygon.bounds().getInfo()['coordinates']
    export_image(red_band, 'red', site_name, region_coords, 10, 'Sentinel2_Images')
    export_image(green_band, 'green', site_name, region_coords, 10, 'Sentinel2_Images')
    export_image(blue_band, 'blue', site_name, region_coords, 10, 'Sentinel2_Images')
    export_image(nir_band, 'nir', site_name, region_coords, 10, 'Sentinel2_Images')

I've tried simplifying the code to just export something to my Google Drive, and that works fine, so it isn't anything to do with accessing my Drive.
